# Django 1.10: When rendering a ModelForm after update, ImageFields are missing when they're changed

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True, null=True)

# forms.py
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
def profile(request, id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, 
                               files=request.FILES or None, 
                               instance=p)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': profile_form})

#profile.html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If a user GETs /profile/1 and 1 exists, they get the form prefilled with all the values, including the image (if any)

If the user then POSTs updates to any of the fields except the image (clearing or changing), The page renders correctly after the update.

However, if the user changes the Image (clear or change), the change is not reflected in the rendered result:  The image is always shown as empty. a quick GET solves the situation and displays the changed situation.

Does anyone know why the image field doesn't show the update in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have to do some sort of redirection to somewhere(obviously with a `GET`) when the profile form is successfully saved? You were always returning `render....` and if you are having a `POST` request the form is going to stay with the `POST` data. So it should be:

```
# views.py
def profile(request, id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=q)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            # do the GET request to some page
            return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': profile_form})
```

Comment: adding return redirect() works, but why would I?  I should have all the data in the profile_form, why does it render differently from an instance with no POST data? It's also an extra http request and an extra DB call.

Comment: The `instance` argument for model form only gives the form access to the object, it doesn't define the data that a form carries. If you have `POST` data in the form, that's what a form would display. Thus it's necessary to have "extra request and db call", check django doc on how to work with a form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view